# Different aspects of married relationship described in the last of the Sheva Brachos?

Tags: sources-mekorot, wedding, niddah, sheva-brachos

In the 6th (at a meal) or 7th (under the Chuppah) of Sheva Brachos, we read the line of גילה רינה, דיצה וחדווה, אהבה ואחווה, ושלום ורעות. I have heard that the first four words are referring to the relationship between a couple when the woman is Tahor and that the last four are referring to the relationship between a couple when the woman is a Niddah.

Does anyone have a source for this? I have heard that the Maharal may have said this but have come up empty locating a source.

Comment: While I haven't located a source, the explanation sounds logical. The translation of the first four items appear to be "external" emotional expressions. The last four - "love, harmony, peace and companionship" are more "internal" and everlasting. It is easy to express "joy, gladness and rejoicing" when you have physical contact with your wife when she is not a niddah. When she is a niddah and you must separate, the other 4 items become more of a challenge and you need to find ways to express them without the physical contact.

Comment: That's a great understanding. If you can't find a source, I'd accept that as an answer

Comment: I have the answer, but I'll only say if you change your username to Yungerman613... Just kidding!

Comment: Very Funny @NBZ. Looking forward to the answer

Comment: @NBZ do you indeed have a source?

Comment: No, sorry, my "Just kidding" went on the first part too. I did actually ask someone I thought would know. He said he remembers the Gra saying something similar. No source though.

Comment: I looked online and discovered that people indeed do quote this in the name of the Maharal but nobody I saw gives a source. I once heard Rabbi Hartman say that people quote things from the Maharal all the time that he doesn't know where they came from...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where it is in the Maharal, though he is quoted as saying this by Tehila Abramov
סוד הנשיות היהודית p64.

I have also heard it quoted in the name of the Ramban.